# How to use GitHub for multiple installations that differ in configuration?

Tags: github, configuration

I am a beginner with GitHub. I have two domoticz installations (Home Automation System) in different places. They differ in script files and some config files that support the installation. But there are also a lot of files (like user defined icons etc) that are the same for both configurations.

Should I fork, or branch on my origin repository?

Or is there any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your specific needs. I will try to point out some aspects you can think about.

### Forking

- You will have the second project as a separate repository.
- Changes in your fork will not affect your other project.
- With a fork you will have a higher isolation and security.
- You can better handle collaborators and external contributors.
- Easier deployment due to the independence of the other project.

### Branching

- Lower isolation of the two projects.
- Maybe a more complex deployment process because of different branches and rules.
- Simpler management of collaborators and contributors.
- Higher chance of merging or pushing into the wrong branch, which will cause errors.

If I had to decide, I would choose the fork option.

For more information you can also have a look at these questions:

- [Forking vs. Branching in GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611256/forking-vs-branching-in-github)
- [Should you fork or branch on Github? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389753/should-you-fork-or-branch-on-github)

Comment: Thnx, Sascha, I was also leaning towards the fork option. The puzzle is the collection of files that is the same for both installations. If something changes or is added there, it should actually go into both repos. Maybe I should go for a fork per installation:
- the origin contains only the common files
- the forks then contain the installation-specific files